# Would learning COM with C/C++ help me understand .NET better?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, com

Often when learning about .NET I run into things that hail from the COM world, or C/C++ (handles, gdi, interop, STA/MTA, etc., the list goes on!).

Would it be worth my time to go learn how to program in COM with C or C++, thus killing two birds with one stone?

Would this deepen my knowledge of developing with .NET? I am tired of the "This HAPPENS BY MAGIC" feeling!

Comment: COM is no longer supported by Microsoft.  Or at least that is my understanding of it.  Why learn something dead if you are trying to get better at .NET.  why not learn a different way of doing things in .NET like freshening up on F# or one of the other 'newer' languages.

Comment: @wheaties Where did you get that startling information from?

Comment: Because we still have to interact with COM all the time (programming for Office, etc.), and a LOT of .NET concepts are based on this stuff, and it seems like they assume "Oh, they know COM, so we will just scratch the surface of the explanation for .NET".

Comment: @wheaties Under the hood of Windows there is a lot of COM, a lot!

Comment: Oh i know.  i used to do cOM programming.  I still have nightmares...

Comment: Actually, COM is not so bad, particularly with all the help that MS development tools give you. If you want something really evil, try CORBA.

Comment: @wheaties - MS likes to rename things to keep the MS programmers tied up relearning what they already knew, and distracted from eg Linux. COM -> DCOM -> ActiveX -> much_of_dotNET ... with incremental changes along the progression. And... yes this is a thinly veiled dig at MS.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth - Hahaha CORBA! They should have called it 'DISTRIBUTED_OVERKILL'!

Comment: @Eric They should have called it "designed by non-programmers" - it's a classic example of design-by-committee where the committee had not clue #1 how it would actually be used. The other classic example of this is OSI, but at least some people did actually use CORBA, including (unhappily) me.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth - I read the entire CORBA Postscript doc set in about 1996 (just because I could ;-) It seemed to me the design attempted to provide a machine to machine communication system that accounted for every possible permutation of bit order, byte order, network order and byte size, Lord knows what else. To be all things to all people. I thought at the high level view that ORBs were neat, but I tried to write code for the sake of learning and found I quickly had to resort to knowledge of CORBA internals. In the end I concluded RPC was maybe less general but more  usable.

Comment: @Eric My big beef is that despite all their efforts, they failed to make the most commonly used datatype - the string - usable from any of their horrible bindings. I had to write a CORBA-based server at an IB, and I could not believe the hoops I had to jump through compared with COM, Tibco et al. Fortunately, I don't believe anyone is using CORBA anymore, except for legacy stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learning COM will help you understand certain portions of .NET better, but they are mainly the portions that deal with COM interop.  It will not help (much) for general .NET development overall, other than in certain scenarios.

That being said, if your primary goal is to learn and be focused in .NET, I would focus on learning some of the newer .NET technologies.  Between WCF, WPF, Silverlight, WF, EF, etc - there's no way one person can become a true expert at all of the .NET technologies already existing, let alone others.  Focusing on the main .NET based technologies that interest you may be a more productive use of your time.

If you want to try to expand your knowledge in general, then COM may be worth learning - but I'd probably personally recommend learning a new language, especially one that uses a very different paradigm than your main .NET language.  For example, studying a functional programming language might really expand your view of programming and be a much better use of your time.

Comment: RE: WCF, WPF, WF...all that stuff is good, but before you delve in to that you really need to understand the fundamentals.  I work with a gent who went straight into silverlight and all he did was build it like it was a vb6 app and didn't bother to learn about things like MVVM or even proper OOP

Comment: Would you recommend something like C++, or F#? What other language should I learn for expanding my knowledge in general?

Comment: @Chris: I completely agree - Learn what you know first,well.

Comment: @Richard: Personally, I'd learn F# over C++ (unless you have a good reason to know/learn C++), if you're coming from C#.  C++ is a very good language, but it's too easy to stick to the same paradigms you use in C#.  F# will force you to think differently.  C++ is great, and templates allow you to do things you can't touch in C#, but I'd still go for something even more different like F# first...

Answer (score 4):

Instead of diving into this, read Don Box's tomes on the .NET framework and why things work the way they do inside .NET.  All magic will be relinquished after this book (though dated, it is still very relavent).

Comment: That would be the same Don Box who's books on COM said that COM was a great (possibly the only) way to architect your applications? The man is a self-serving bullsh*t artist.

Answer (score 3):

My personal opinion...keep in mind this is just my opinion:

I am glad that I learned .NET first.  I was not constrained to think about things like binary compatibility and activeX.  These are legacy concepts that I have really only needed when dealing with older COM libraries.

I will admit that going back and learning COM was useful in certain aspects as you really should understand how compatibility works.  Though, my situation was a little different in that I learned about COM with vb6 which can be VERY different.

I would say learn .NET fairly well first, but go back and learn about MTA and multi-threading with C++.  This still seems to be an area where many people have hesitated to say that .NET is better.

To add one last thought, I work with many legacy programmers that come form the COM world.  They get so stuck in that world that it prohibits them from moving on.  If I see something like clsOrder one more time I may barf.  Do yourself a favor and learn how to actually program in .NET.  Don't just program vb6/c/c++ in .NET.  It's a huge waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Learning anything will help your understanding of similar concepts, so sure why not.

Comment: Well, I'm look for something a little more commital than "sure, why not". The reason why not is that I have my hands full learning all the other things, so if this isn't going to cause a major positive impact on my understanding, I don't have the time to waste.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

It can't hurt, but if you don't know C/C++ very well, especially pointers and memory allocation, you may want to brush up on those before jumping straight in to interfacing with COM objects.

Comment: Learning COM can and will probably hurt is feelings!

Answer (score 0):

"C/C++" suggests to me that you definitely don't know, well, anything about it. I would skip it if you just want to know about .NET, as they will likely come with relevant documentation that will explain how it works from the .NET side. However, if you want to learn more generally, or the kinds of things involved in the implementation details of .NET, like the magic that's involved in interop, then I'd definitely go for C++.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't learn c++/C for the com I would learn it because its a very different way of looking at how to structure problems and solutions.  Any of the higher level languages do a lot by magic and the closer you go to the machine the less that happens.